# Can tar be forced to exit on the first error?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gnu, tar

By default, for many kinds of errors `tar` prints a message to stderr and then continues on its way -- the errors it calls "recoverable" errors, typically errors that relate to a single file or archive member, like permissions problems.

Sometimes this behavior is really obnoxious. E.g., if I'm untarring an archive and the disk is full, then I may get something like this:

```
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_cgist.so: Wrote only 2048 of 10240 bytes
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_csmo.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_csvmodel.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_knn.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_libsvm.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/_mylibsvm.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/cgist.py: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: python-lib/PyML/classifiers/ext/csmo.py: Cannot write: No space left on device
```

that can go on for thousands of lines in a big archive. If this happens in a script, I'd much rather `tar` just exited promptly so I can give a prompt error to the user.

Is there any way to force `tar` to exit on the first error it sees?  I don't see it in a scan of `tar --help`.  Any sane recipe for a wrapper script to accomplish this purpose would also be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to redirect the standard error output to `/dev/full`, e.g.:

```
tar ... 2>/dev/full
```

This will cause tar to fail when it tries to output a warning message into `stderr`.

Comment: +1 Nice.  Never even heard of `/dev/full`.  Useful tip.

Comment: Clever idea, but it doesn't work. At least not with GNU tar 1.22, the version I have on hand. Stracing the `tar` process confirms that it cheerfully continues on after each write to standard error fails.

Have you actually tried this idea? What version of `tar`?

Comment: I tried with other applications. `tar` probably just ignores the error. There need to be a pipe so that `SIGPIPE` is sent to `tar` in case of error to knock it off.